# Fetching data from bigquery without repetition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using Google's bigquery Python API, is it possible to fetch data from from big query table (GCP) in batches without repetition (i.e., downloading a large dataset in small batches rather than all at once)?

For example, if I have a table with 10 million rows, can I run 10 iterations of data fetching where in each iteration 1 million unique and new rows are downloaded without repetition (i.e., the same row is fetched only once across all 10 iterations)?

Comment: I can see this [doc](https://dataform.co/blog/removing-duplicates-bigquery) might be help you to fetch the distinct data from a set of records

Comment: @Mahboob, my primary goal is to download the entire dataset in batches rather than all at once.

Answer (score 0):

i use pandas for that things

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas_gbq
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('yourkey.json')
10MrowsQuery = f'select * from 10MrowTable")'
dataframe = pd.read_gbq(10MrowsQuery, project_id="yourgcpprojectname", dialect='standard', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: I am aware of how to download data from bq via Pandas. I am looking into downloading a large table in batches rather than all at once.